# Javascript: GET not supported for method Error

Tags: javascript, express

I have `` app.get( `${base}/:id/statements/fromDate/toDate`, doGetStatement( app )) ; `` inside my routes method, and from `'https://localhost:2345/accounts/365_66/statements/2021-02-01/2021-02-28'`, I'd like to extract the `fromDate` and `toDate` fields. With this code inside my `doGetStatement` method:

```
  const id = req.params.id ;
  const from = req.body.fromDate ;
  const to = req.body.toDate ;
```

I'm receiving the error  `"GET not supported for /accounts/1_99/statements/2021-02-01/2021-02-28"`. How can I properly get the fields fromDate and toDate?

Comment: Your endpoint is `${base}/:id/statements/fromDate/toDate` but you call `/accounts/1_99/statements/2021-02-01/2021-02-28` which is not the same endpoint. You're embedding the `fromDate` and `toDate` in the path but expect the get them as body. Yet also the endpoint is declared as a GET and thus cannot have a body.

Comment: You need to add `:` in front of `fromDate` and `toDate`.